# RVM Multi-user and missing ~/.rvm dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, debian, gitlab

I've just installed RVM in multi-user mode. There was an application (GitLab) previously installed in single-user mode but i needed to reinstall RVM to support multi users.

The problem is that now, application throws error

> /usr/bin/env: /home/git/.rvm/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

here and there almost allways, when i'm trying to run any command with `rake/bundle/rails`. Is there any way to change that somewhere in the config to make my application look for ruby in the correct path (which is in `/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby`) or i need to create a symlink or, even worse, edit each path in my app?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you don't want to use both system-wide and single user RVM installations at the same time with the same user. I'm not sure if this is impossible, but I'm quite sure it is a good idea.

To the user that runs your application, you need to be sure that it is not loading at any point of his login  the file `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. This will hopefully make it load the system-wide installation, and this should work normally. You need to look for where this is being loaded, most obvious candidates are `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.bash_alias` and `.profile`, and the system versions of these files if they doesn't exists in the user home. You can check [this link](http://savage.net.au/Linux/html/bash.files.html) for more info on this.

Now, if you want to be a good boy, I would suggest not keep both installations on the same system at all. Remove system-wide installation and use the normal installation. Then you will need to download, compile and bunldle gitlab again, but eventually it will work.

Comment: I'm actually forced to run those two apps on the same machine. One uses 1.8.7, the second one 2.0.0. Anyway, i've managed to fix this by creating a symlink. It's probably a really dirty fix but it works. I don't have anything related to `rvm` in the mentioned bash files. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by creating a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/rvm/ /home/git/.rvm
```

It's really dirty i think so any better solutions are welcome.